# PHP: Why email not support html

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I try to send an email from my web site, I received email but not support HTML.

Here is my code:-

```
////////
        $headers = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n"; 
        $headers .= "Register: Super market\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";


        //$header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
        $subject = "Register in Super market";
        $email_to = EMAIL;

        $emailMessage = "<b>NO :</b>  " . $aid."\n";    
        $emailMessage .= "<b>Name :</b>  " . $firstname.' '.$fathername.' '.$familyname. "\n"; 
        $emailMessage .= "<b>Tell :</b>  " . $tell . "\n\n";
        $emailMessage .= "<b>Fax :</b>  " . $fax . "\n\n";
        $emailMessage .= "<b>Email :</b>  " . $email . "\n\n";      

        //use php's mail function to send the email
        @mail($email_to, $subject ,$emailMessage ,$headers );
```

**Update:**

Hi every one.

I set an [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623238/php-why-email-not-support-html/26623274) here and [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623238/php-why-email-not-support-html/26623274#26623274) successful

But now i need to add some file as attachment.

So, I have 2 variable, That save the file upload into DB like this:-

```
$filenameword
$filenamezip
```

How can set this tow variable as file attachment in email inbox.

```
////////
    $headers = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";  // See the s at the end of $headers
    $headers .= "Register: Super market\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";


    //$header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $subject = "Register in Super market";
    $email_to = EMAIL;

    $emailMessage = "<b>NO :</b>  " . $aid."\n";    
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Name :</b>  " . $firstname.' '.$fathername.' '.$familyname. "\n"; 
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Tell :</b>  " . $tell . "\n\n";
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Fax :</b>  " . $fax . "\n\n";
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Email :</b>  " . $email . "\n\n";      

    //use php's mail function to send the email
    mail($email_to, $subject ,$emailMessage ,$headers );
```

Comment: Hey, you've missed the <html> and <body> tags..

Comment: must be $headers not $header on line 1

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code.

You are assigning header strings to `$headers` but you're passing `$header` to the mail function.

Also please no `@` before functions. It's a bad practice.

```
////////
    $headers = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";  // See the s at the end of $headers
    $headers .= "Register: Super market\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";


    //$header = "From: $email\n" . "Reply-To: $email\n";
    $subject = "Register in Super market";
    $email_to = EMAIL;

    $emailMessage = "<b>NO :</b>  " . $aid."\n";    
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Name :</b>  " . $firstname.' '.$fathername.' '.$familyname. "\n"; 
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Tell :</b>  " . $tell . "\n\n";
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Fax :</b>  " . $fax . "\n\n";
    $emailMessage .= "<b>Email :</b>  " . $email . "\n\n";      

    //use php's mail function to send the email
    mail($email_to, $subject ,$emailMessage ,$headers );  // See the s at the end of $headers
```

Comment: I don't understand you ,, can you edit my code and put it in your answer

Comment: Small addition: the matter of using `@` is not just being "bad practice", it's that by suppressing errors debugging becomes a search in the dark. Considering also that `$headers .=` would have thrown an E_NOTICE btw, so might be error reporting is also too low, error suppressors or not.
Suggestion to @RashaSami : if you're sending e-mails in more places, or for a more robust solution, consider using a proven php library like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer

Comment: See http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php for an example how to attach files to the email